# Reducing the number of observables in Factor Analysis

Tags: optimization, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I have $k$ observables (e.g. questions in a questionnaire) and $n$ observational units (e.g. respondents of the questionnaire). Let's call the observation matrix $X$.
Let's assume I have performed a [Factor Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis) and arrived at a latent space of dimension $m < k$.

Now, the goal is to reduce the number of observables used for future studies. For example, if observables are questions on a questionnaire, it is desired to minimize the number of questions not to annoy people. For simplicity, let us assume that the cost of extra observables grows linearly.

I would guess that this problem is well-known in the right circles. What is it called? Can you recommend an algorithm that is used to solve it?

It would be interesting to see how uncertainty in Y changes with different choices of the observable subset.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is called the [Varimax rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varimax_rotation). In Factor Analysis, the likelihood of your samples does not change if you perform a rotation of your factor matrix. Varimax finds the rotation that maximizes the variances of the squared loadings, hence resulting in more interpretable components: each component will be related to only a few observables (instead of being spread across all of them), which may help you to prune your observables.

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks!